# How to use script in Wordpress installation?

Tags: jquery, scripts

I have a static HTML web page that I would like to recreate on a Wordpress website.

The page has a fake survey with a series of questions. Users respond by clicking on one of several buttons which loads the next question using a fade-in/out effect.

The static HTML page contains the following 2 script tags in the footer:

`<script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

`<script src="js/questions.js"></script>`

I say "fake survey" because it doesn't actually make any difference which button is clicked on and the responses are not recorded.

Here is the `questions.js` JS file linked to in the script tag above and used to generate the fade-in/out effects:

```
function startCheck() {
var e = $(".overlay-checker"),
    t = $(".overlay-checker-points > li");
for (t.hide(), e.fadeIn(), i = 0; i < t.length; i++) setTimeout(function() {
    $(".overlay-checker-points").find(":hidden").first().fadeIn()
}, 1500 * (i + 1));
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = $(".redirectNow").attr("href")
}, 1500 * t.length + 2e3)
}

function toggleDiv(e) {
$(e).toggle()
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#questionWrapper .question").first().show(), $("#questionWrapper
```

.answer").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(), "answer cannotContinue" != $(this).attr("class") ? 
   ($(this).parent(".question").fadeOut(200), 
   $(this).parent().next(".question").length ? 
   $(this).parent().next(".question").delay(200).fadeIn() : startCheck()) : 
   alert("Sorry, you need to be 16 or above to participate in this survey.")
    })
   });

Also included in the static HTML page, is the following jQuery link:

`<script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

My Wordpress site links to jQuery in the head using the following script tag:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywordpress-site.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp'></script>`

I thought I could just add the necessary classes and ids to the HTML of the Wordpress page and add the fade-in/out script to the footer but haven't been able to get it to work.

jQuery is already linked to in the header so I don't need to link to it again although I see it's a different version.

Should I deregister the original script and include a link to the same jQuery script as included in the static HTML page?

Comment: Never deregister the original jQuery, how are you including your `js/questions.js` script? What does your browser dev tools console say?

Comment: @TomJNowell, I tried deregistering the Wordpress jQuery script anyway. I created a folder in the root directory and placed both files in there. I'm using `wp_enqueue_script();` to print the scripts. The `js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js` script is in the header and the `js/questions.js` script is in the footer. I'm not getting any errors in the console but it's not working either.

Comment: @TomJNowell, I followed your advice and removed the deregister script function and put both scripts from the static HTML page in the footer but there was still nothing happening when I clicked on the buttons. After re-checking the static HTML file I realized I needed to add the `.answer` class to the button ` a` tags  on the Wordpress page. After doing that and testing it again, the page redirects to an "undefined" 404 page. The following error message is in the console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`.

Comment: Can you format your questions.js? It's all on one line, it's difficult to read, also there's no HTML markup. There's a very good chance though that this is just a generic JS question

Comment: I finally got it to work. I removed the `js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js` script and because of the different HTML structure on the Wordpress page as compared to the static HTML page, I had to change .parent to .parents. in the `js/questions.js` script and edit it so it worked in jQuery.noConflict() mode.